# Explain verse 3:178

Tags: quran, tafseer

It says here that the life of unbelievers is prolonged not for their benefit, but only ("innama") so that they sin more.

> And let not those who disbelieve ever think that [because] We extend
> their time [of enjoyment] it is better for them. We only extend it for
> them so that they may increase in sin, and for them is a humiliating
> punishment. (178)

But what about those unbelievers who, after their unbelief, repented and became Muslims? Didn't they benefit?

Answer (score 0):

A common issue when people read the Quran is that they read it atomistically. God has specified multiple times in the Quran that if the disbelievers repent or desist, then all will be forgiven.

> Say to the disbelievers that, if they desist, what is past will be forgiven them, but if they relapse, then the wont of those of old has already passed.
>
> <sup>[Quran 8:38](https://archive.org/details/the-study-quran-a-new-translation-and-commentary-by-seyyed-hossein-nasr/008%20al-Anf%C4%81l%20Seyyed%20Hossein%20Nasr/page/1050/mode/1up)</sup>

> Whosoever does evil or wrongs himself, and then seeks forgiveness of God, he will find God Forgiving, Merciful.
>
> <sup>[Quran 4:110](https://archive.org/details/the-study-quran-a-new-translation-and-commentary-by-seyyed-hossein-nasr/004%20Al-Nis%C4%81%20Seyyed%20Hossein%20Nasr/page/557/mode/1up)</sup>

So whichever disbeliever (or believer) does wrong and seeks forgiveness, they will find God forgiving. For disbelievers that don't repent or desist then the message of Quran 3:178 remains.

Furthermore, let's understand what happens when someone disbelieves. When someone disbelieves, they are essentially ignoring or neglecting God. By ignoring and neglecting God, God neglects or abandons them in return. And if God who is pure goodness and the only entity and being in existence that can give guidance, is neglecting or abandoning a disbeliever, all that disbeliever has left is misguidance.

> It may be that your Lord will have mercy upon you, **but if you revert, We shall revert**. And We have made Hell a prison for the disbelievers.
>
> <sup>[Quran 17:8](https://archive.org/details/the-study-quran-a-new-translation-and-commentary-by-seyyed-hossein-nasr/017%20al-Isr%C4%81%CA%BE%20Seyyed%20Hossein%20Nasr/page/1518/mode/1up)</sup>

> Satan has overwhelmed them, and so made them **forget the remembrance of God**. They are the party of Satan. Lo! The party of Satan are losers.
>
> <sup>[Quran 58:19](https://archive.org/details/the-study-quran-a-new-translation-and-commentary-by-seyyed-hossein-nasr/058%20al-Muj%C4%81dilah%20Seyyed%20Hossein%20Nasr/page/2987/mode/1up)</sup>

> The hypocrites, men and women, are like unto one another, enjoining wrong, forbidding right, clutching their hands shut. **They forgot God; so He forgot them**. Truly the hypocrites are iniquitous.
>
> <sup>[Quran 9:67](https://archive.org/details/the-study-quran-a-new-translation-and-commentary-by-seyyed-hossein-nasr/009%20al-Tawbah%20Seyyed%20Hossein%20Nasr/page/1123/mode/1up)</sup>

> And it will be said, “**Today We forget you just as you forgot the meeting with this your Day**; your refuge is the Fire and you have no helpers. That is because you took the signs of God in mockery and the life of this world has deluded you.” So today they will not be removed from it; nor can they make amends.
>
> <sup>[Quran 45:34-35](https://archive.org/details/the-study-quran-a-new-translation-and-commentary-by-seyyed-hossein-nasr/045%20al-J%C4%81thiyah%20Seyyed%20Hossein%20Nasr/page/2711/mode/1up)</sup>

So if a disbeliever is neglected or abandoned by God (due to them neglecting God first), then all that disbeliever will be left with is the rest of his/her life to indulge in misguidance and sins which corresponds with messaging Quran 3:178.

Comment: But does the unbeliever's choice between remaining in error or going the way depend on himself or on God according to the Qur'an?

Comment: And could you help me with one verse? At 42:45 it says: "And you will see them being exposed to it [i.e., the Fire], humbled from humiliation, looking from [behind] a covert glance. And those who had believed will say, "Indeed, the [true] losers are the ones who lost themselves and their families on the Day of Resurrection. Unquestionably, the wrongdoers are in an enduring punishment." ([42] Ash-Shuraa : 45). So it says here that sinners (zalimun) will be in Hell forever?

Comment: A person's choice to believe or disbelieve is ultimately on the person. God has given us free will and we are accountable for our own actions. If you incline towards God, then he will give you guidance. If you decline God, then no one can give you guidance and the disbeliever will continue down a path of misguidance accumulating sins until they die unless they repent or desist from what they're doing.

Comment: Regarding hell, the majority view is that some disbelievers will be in hell forever, verses such as 4:168-169 verbally express so. But there are also views held by some scholars such as Ibn Al-Qayyim, Al-Ghazali, and more that while hell and its flames are eternal, it'll be empty one day, meaning all dwellers of hell will be removed from it someday. I haven't studied enough into their view but it's interesting.